# Delete \xa0 at the end of a unicode

Tags: python, regex

I have a string, such as u'jdiajsi--dasdsa\xa0'. I need to get rid of \xao and obtain u'jdiajsi--dasdsa'.

First, I tried str.replace("\xa0", ", "), but it does not work. Then, I change to re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', str), but the result is "jdiajsi dasdsa". The two dashes are gone...

```
str = "jdiajsi--dasdsa\xa0"
str.replace("\xa0", ", ") #fail
re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', str)  #fail
```

The first result is no change, the second one miss --. The expected result is "jdiajsi--dasdsa"

The input is unicode rather than a string

Comment: `.replace` returns a new string, also if you should not use str and finally do `s = s.replace("\xa0", "")`

Comment: Hi, it's possible to use hex codes in python strings. The string can be replaced with: `newString = oldString.replace('\xa0', '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are immutable; none of their methods, nor any function, can change them in place, they always *return* a new string. You need to assign them to something to see the changed version, e.g.:

```
mystr = "jdiajsi--dasdsa\xa0"
mystr = mystr.replace("\xa0", ", ")
mystr = re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', mystr)
```

Note that I changed the name of the variable; naming a variable `str` cuts off access to the `str` constructor, which will eventually byte you.

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake. The type of input is a unicode rather than a string. I guess this is the reason replace method not work